# error messege expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token while entire program is written correctly?

Tags: c, stack, token

hello i am getting an error in following program while execution.
this program is exactly correct according to me but while running on gcc compiler,a error message showed.
please have a look at the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 5
{
    int stk[MAXSIZE];
    int top;
};
typedef struct stack STACK;
STACK s;

void push(void);
int pop(void);
void display(void);
void main()
{
    int choice;
    int option=1;
    s.top=-1;

    while(option)
    {
        printf("___________________________________\n");
        printf("1-->PUSH\n");
        printf("2-->POP\n");
        printf("3-->DISPLAY\n");
        printf("4-->EXIT\n");
        printf("____________________________________\n");
        printf("Enter your choice");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:push();
                   break;
            case 2:pop();
                   break;
            case 3:display();
                   break;
            case 4:return;
        }
    printf("Do you want to continue(type 0 or 1)?\n");
    scanf("%d",&option);
    }
}
```

the compiler says  expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token.What is the meaning of this?
tell me the possible solution.

Comment: You seem to have 'accidentally' deleted a line: `struct stack` just after `#define MAXSIZE 5`

Comment: A word of advice: If the compiled reports a syntax error in your code, don't tell everyone that your code is "exactly correct". Compilers rarely get things like this wrong. Also, the error occurred at compilation time, not during execution.

Comment: `i am getting an error in following program while execution` No. you are getting error while compiling.

Comment: `main()` have to return `int` and not `void`.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare stack as

```
struct stack <--- missed it
{
    int stk[MAXSIZE];
     int top;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `struct` data type and struct name in code

```
{
    int stk[MAXSIZE];
    int top;
};
```

It should

```
struct stack
{
    int stk[MAXSIZE];
    int top;
};
```

Also you can define it as `typedef struct` and remove line `typedef struct stack STACK;`

Like

```
typedef struct
{
    int stk[MAXSIZE];
    int top;
}STACK;

STACK s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Write your structure like this

```
typedef struct stack
{
    int stk[MAXSIZE];
    int top;
}STACK;
STACK s;
```